# Implementation of where clause in Laravel find()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Here is my code:

```
public function order($id)
{
    $product = Product::find($id);
    $other_products = Product::find($id)->toArray();
    return view('products.order',['product'=>$product,'other'=>$other_products]);
}
```

So my question is how can i exclude `$product` from the `$other_products` query, more like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE product != $id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `where()`

```
$other_products = Product::where('id', '!=', $id)->get()->toArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$other_products = Product::where('id', '!=', $id)
```

OR

```
$other_products = Product::whereNotIn('id', [$id])
```

OR

```
$other_products = Product::where('id', '<>', $id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$other_products = Product::where('id','!=',$id)->get();
```

Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses you can build queries using elequent models